# Simplest method for declaratively applying a SQL schema to a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

### Goal: I'm looking for a declarative and repeatable way of "applying" SQL table schemas to a database

### What I've tried

Below is a SQL script that does what I want (as best as I can tell from my superficial knowledge of MySQL and with some manual testing):

1. If the table doesn't exist, it creates it
2. If the table does exist, it ensures it has the desired schema

```sql
-- create table

create table if not exists `EntryType` (
  `EntryCode` varchar(2) primary key,
  `Name` varchar(256) not null
) engine = InnoDB default charset = utf8mb4;

-- modify table

alter table `EntryType`
  engine = InnoDB,
  character set utf8mb4;

alter table `EntryType`
  modify `EntryCode` varchar(2),
  drop primary key,
  add primary key (`EntryCode`);

alter table `EntryType`
  modify `Name` varchar(256) not null;
```

### Problems with this approach

- duplication: repeating column definitions, engine, and character set twice
- laborious: it takes a lot of time to craft these queries and manually test them each time a table is added or modified
- imperative: this is fundamentally an imperative approach to something that should be declarative

### Question: Is there some safe means of declaratively "applying" a table schema?

- idempotent: can be applied any number of times with the exact same end state
- works whether or not the table already exists
- works whether or not the table already contains data
- works whether or not there are constraints and foreign key references to other tables

### Preferences:

1. A pure SQL solution would be ideal
2. A reliable and easy-to-use CLI solution would work
3. Would also accept a relatively simple hand-coded SQL or Node.js solution

Comment: You want [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io). It's not a pure-SQL solution, but there is none that is pure-SQL. Skeema does what you describe.

Comment: You're describing what's commonly called "migrations" and there are dozens of tools to help you do this. If you like Node, then [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) has a migration system you can use.

Comment: Skeema indeed looks like it does what I'm looking for.  Giving that a try.

Comment: @tadman, migrations use still use imperative approach, but I'm looking for a declarative solution.

Comment: SQL alone cannot tackle this problem because SQL is not feature-complete enough to do it. You will need something else to interface with the server and do it. Any migration system that's purely "declarative" is in practice total trash as it will make a mess of things in short order. You *want* control over what it's doing.

Comment: Your "pure SQL" solution is really not that great as those "alter table" statements cannot be readily undone. A good migration system will generate inverse migrations so you can roll-back if necessary. Since you're using MySQL you don't have the luxury of transactional schema changes like you do on other systems, so once each statement is applied there is no going back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), the [Skeema.io](https://www.skeema.io/) CLI ended up working out pretty well for a few simple tests.

The docs don't do a great job of guiding you through the setup process, so I captured what I figured out here.

### First-time schema fetch

Download a ZIP file from [the github repo releases page](https://github.com/skeema/skeema/releases) and unzip it.

Put the `skeema` binary somewhere in your project. Inside my project root, I put
it in a `bin` folder, so from the project root the path is `./bin/skeema`.

Then, make sure your MySQL database is running and you have the connection info. Mine was running locally on `127.0.0.1`, port `3306` (the MySQL default, so I didn't have to enter it).

From the project root, I entered the following command to initialize things by fetching the current state of the database schema.

```sh
./bin/skeema init -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p --schema=MyDB -d schemas
```

A few specifics:

- I used the `--schema=MyDB` option to track just one database. If you leave this out, it will track all databases it finds.
- The `-d schemas` option says to store the config and schema files in the `schemas` directory.
- Using `-p` option, it will prompt you for a password after running the command.

It then connects to and inspects your database, creates the `schemas` directory, and write some files there that represent the current schema state. You'll notice a `.skeema` config file and a `.sql` file for each table in the database.

### Config tweaks

I then went into the `schemas/.skeema` config file and renamed the `[production]` section to `[development]` because this is actually a dev instance. By doing this, I'll have to specify `development` in every command because `skeema` assumes `production` as the default.

[Optional, Node.js projects only] The `skeema` command is intended to be run from within the folder that contains the `.skeema` config file, but I don't want to worry about this, so I created a script in my Node.js `package.json` file that basically does this for me every time.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "skeema": "cd schemas && ../bin/skeema"
  },
}
```

Now I can type the following from the project root (or anywhere else within the project):

```sh
npm run skeema
```

### A first schema change

While in the `schemas/.skeema` config file, I made a few changes to correct a character encoding mistake when setting up these tables:

- changed `default-character-set=utf8` to `default-character-set=utf8mb4`
- changed `default-collation=utf8_general_ci` to `default--collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

I also added a new column to one of the `.sql` files:

```
CREATE TABLE `EntryType` (
  `EntryCode` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `Foo` varchar(3), -- new column
  PRIMARY KEY (`EntryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

### Pushing a schema change

The first step is to see if there are schema differences:

```sh
npm run skeema diff development
```

The output should the schema changes you made, for example:

```sh
2020-07-02 19:32:14 [INFO]  Generating diff of 127.0.0.1:3306 MyDB vs
                            /Users/chriscalo/Projects/my-project/schemas/*.sql
-- instance: 127.0.0.1:3306
USE `MyDB`;
ALTER TABLE `EntryType` ADD COLUMN `Foo` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL;
2020-07-02 19:32:15 [INFO]  127.0.0.1:3306 MyDB: diff complete
```

And then push the schema change:

```sh
yarn run skeema push development
```

That's it!